# Latex output in R

Tags: r, datatable, latex, r-markdown, output

I'm using the package `stargazer` to represent some regression outputs in a unique table. The problem is that it gives me a LATEX output ( I'm new in this kind of things)

To better explain

```
stargazer(reg_a, reg_b, reg_c,  reg_d, reg_e, align=TRUE)
```

It gives me this as output

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.3 by Marek Hlavac, Social Policy Institute. E-mail: marek.hlavac at gmail.com
% Date and time: ven, mar 17, 2023 - 16:11:49
% Requires LaTeX packages: dcolumn 
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{log(tpens)} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 sex & 0.265^{***} & 0.170^{***} & 0.171^{***} & 0.170^{***} \\ 
  & (0.010) & (0.010) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 eta & -0.003^{***} & -0.001 & -0.001^{*} & -0.001^{*} \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 ireg & -0.008^{***} & -0.006^{***} & -0.005^{***} & -0.005^{***} \\ 
  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 studio\_lev2 & 0.129^{***} & 0.115^{***} & 0.114^{***} & 0.114^{***} \\ 
  & (0.014) & (0.013) & (0.013) & (0.013) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 studio\_lev3 & 0.422^{***} & 0.406^{***} & 0.403^{***} & 0.404^{***} \\ 
  & (0.022) & (0.021) & (0.021) & (0.021) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 type\_jobManager & 0.473^{***} & 0.426^{***} & 0.422^{***} & 0.422^{***} \\ 
  & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 type\_jobMiddle-class\_worker & 0.204^{***} & 0.170^{***} & 0.166^{***} & 0.166^{***} \\ 
  & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 type\_jobSelf-Employed & -0.134^{***} & -0.178^{***} & -0.182^{***} & -0.182^{***} \\ 
  & (0.013) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 sector & 0.049^{***} & 0.050^{***} & 0.050^{***} & 0.050^{***} \\ 
  & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 acontrib &  & 0.016^{***} & 0.016^{***} & 0.016^{***} \\ 
  &  & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 dislav &  &  & -0.088^{***} & -0.089^{***} \\ 
  &  &  & (0.016) & (0.017) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 nesplav &  &  &  & 0.003 \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.009) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 Constant & 6.876^{***} & 6.191^{***} & 6.233^{***} & 6.229^{***} \\ 
  & (0.048) & (0.052) & (0.052) & (0.053) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5,936} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5,812} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5,812} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5,812} \\ 
R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.416} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.488} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.490} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.490} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.415} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.487} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.489} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.489} \\ 
Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.321 (df = 5926)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.299 (df = 5801)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.298 (df = 5800)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.298 (df = 5799)} \\ 
F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{468.804$^{***}$ (df = 9; 5926)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{552.450$^{***}$ (df = 10; 5801)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{507.248$^{***}$ (df = 11; 5800)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{464.915$^{***}$ (df = 12; 5799)} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I've already tried to install the `Requires LaTeX packages: dcolumn`  but nothing changes... I still get this code as output

How can I see the table from this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stargazer creates a table in latex code. So if you want to see the output, you could create a `Rmarkdown` pdf document with `results = 'asis'` in the code chunk. Here is some reproducible code using the built-in dataset attitude:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to get text output on the console use `type = "text"`

```
library(stargazer)
fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)
stargazer(fm, type = "text")
```

giving:

```
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                              demand           
-----------------------------------------------
Time                          1.721*           
                              (0.639)          
                                               
Constant                      8.521**          
                              (2.659)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                     6             
R2                             0.645           
Adjusted R2                    0.556           
Residual Std. Error       3.085 (df = 4)       
F Statistic             7.265* (df = 1; 4)     
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

or display it in a browser using HTML:

```
library(htmltools)
library(stargazer)

fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)
html_print(HTML(stargazer(fm, type = "html")))
```